# Does Travis CI integrates with Pager Duty?

Tags: travis-ci, pagerduty

Is there a way to configure PagerDuty alerts on Travis CI builds? To reframe can we trigger PagerDuty alerts from Travis CI.

I could not find any information on google, do the two even integrate?

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool in this repository. Hope it helps:

https://github.com/PagerDuty/pagebreak

You just need to add this to your `.travis.yml`:

```
notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
    - <travis-pagerduty-service>@<subdomain>.pagerduty.com
    on_success: never
    on_failure: always
```